# how to remove and create new ul li tag in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jscript.net

Can anyone help me to get this work in d3js

My html tag are as below

```
<div id="source1"><ul><li>Source</li></ul></div>
```

i want to modify the `<li>Source</li>` with `<li>some other text</li>` by removing all the UL LI tags in DIV id source1 and creating new UL LI tags in div id source1

My code is here

```
d3.selectAll("ul").remove()
```

`d3.selectAll("li").remove()`

```
var test=document.getElementbyId('source1');
var ul=document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(test);
test.appendChild(ul);
var li=document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);
li.innerHTML="some other text";
```

Comment: and what's exactly your problem?

Comment: What you really want? Do you want to remove `<div id="source1"><ul><li>Source</li></ul></div>` the inner text which is in between <li> tag.

Comment: i want to replace the li text with my new text

Comment: First you remove UL LI and then re-create UL LI. It is better to update LI only.

Comment: @user3420762, i have tried to remove UL and LI Tags and get success but i can'r recreate my UL LI in <DIV id="Source1"> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is code that should work :

```
var test=document.getElementById('source1');
var li=test.children[0].children[0];
li.innerHTML="some other text";
```

Instead of recreating element you can change text only.

Comment: getElementbyId must be getElementById.

Comment: @user3420762 :D Typo :). Should i attach your fiddle ? or you want to write your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If your moto is to just edit the text in the li tag, you can go for "innerHtml" javascript method. This is the best method
Eg.

```
<div id="source1"><ul><li id="liId">Source</li></ul></div>
 document.getElementById('liId').innerHTML="Some other text";
```

If you want to replace element(in your case, which is not required) you can use this,

```
<div id="source1">
<ul><li id="liId">Source</li></ul>
</div>

<script>
var para = document.createElement("li");
var node = document.createTextNode("Some other Text");
para.appendChild(node);

var parent = document.getElementById("source1");
var child = document.getElementById("liId");
parent.replaceChild(para,child);
 </script>
```

Hope this helps